# permission denied for database "postgres" DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to deploy an API to create a dev environment using heroku. I successfully pushed my project to heroku and added the add-on, but now when i try to create the database (heroku run php bin/console doctrine:database:create), i have the following error:
permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege.
I tried to find where I can change the permissions but I couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku Postgres automatically creates the database on your behalf. To prevent accidents and other issues, creating a database is prohibited which is why you're seeing `"postgres" DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege`.

Instead of running `heroku run php bin/console doctrine:database:create` you need to run your migrations. I'm not familiar with doctrine but it might look something like `heroku run php bin/console doctrine:database:execute`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, you for your answer. To solve my issue, I just skip this command and create schema.
But do you know how can I see the database created and where can I edit it if it's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "see the database"? You can open a psql session with `heroku pg:psql -a $APP_NAME` which will allow you to execute arbitrary SQL statements. There are also tools such as PGAdmin that give similar functionality with a graphical interface.

Comment: I used PGAdmin tu edit something in database. Thanks a lot ofr your help